# How to resize x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

```
df_train = pd.read_csv('../input/titanic/train.csv')
df_train.groupby('Age')['Survived'].mean().plot.bar(rot=0, title='Age',edgecolor="k")
plt.show()
```

[image: X represent age and Y represent survived rate]

I want to resize the x-axis range, but I don't know how to do that. The range I want to resize is [under 20, under 40, under 60, under 80]. X represent age and Y represent survived rate

Comment: Did you try to filter your data for those ranges before plotting? Did you want to make subplots of the different ranges. Your question is pretty broad. `but I don't know how to do that.` - how much time did you spend with the documentation and did you find anything that came close to what you want to do? This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: you can try histogram for frequency , `df_train.groupby('Age')['Survived'].mean().hist(bins=4)` or use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html?highlight=cut#pandas-cut)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your data into age groups before plotting:

```py
age_group = pd.cut(df_train['Age'], bins=range(0,100,20), right=False).rename(None)
df_train.groupby(age_group)['Survived'].mean().plot.bar(rot=0, title='Age',edgecolor="k")
```

[image]

---

If you want more polished labels:

```py
bins = np.arange(0, 100, 20, dtype='int')
labels = [f'Under {i}' for i in bins[1:]]
age_group = pd.cut(df_train['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False).rename(None)

df_train.groupby(age_group)['Survived'].mean().plot.bar(rot=0, title='Age',edgecolor="k")
```

[image]